# Sorting by aggregate field in R

Tags: r, dplyr

```
stackedBarChart <- read.csv("StackedBarChart.csv")
ggplot(stackedBarChart, aes(x=FieldName, y=Quantity, fill=Decision)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
stackedBarChart %>% arrange(quantity)
```

What I want to do is sort the field by the combined total. This is the code i have tried, but it is not working

```
by_field_name <- group_by(stackedBarChart, FieldName)
summarise(by_field_name, sum(Quantity))
```

Here are the lines from my data set,

```
FieldName Quantity  Decision
Issue1   175    Rejected
Issue1   117    Accepted
Issue2   238    Rejected
Issue2   10     Accepted
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend treating it as a factor and just setting the order of the levels.

```
stackedBarChart %>%
mutate(FieldName = factor(FieldName),
       FieldName = reorder(FieldName, Quantity, FUN = sum)) %>%
arrange(FieldName)
```

Having the levels of the factor in order is also the best way to have `ggplot` aware of the order.

Comment: The problem is for my stacked bar chart. I want to sort each unique field by the total of Issue1, Issue2 etc. So in this case, it would be (175+117=292) and Issue 2(238+10-248).

Comment: That's what this code does. (I just added `FUN = sum` in case you have fields with different numbers of rows, by default it was sorting by the means.) Default sort order is always lowest to highest (1 comes before 2, a comes before b). If you want to reverse that, changed `Quantity` to `-Quantity` in my code.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and report back.